# How to extract row before and after when flag change from 0 to 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe , i want to extract 2 rows before flag change from 0 to one and get row where value 'B' is minimum , also extract two rows after flag 1 and get row with minimum value of 'B'

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]})

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,1],
                     'B':[4,1],
                     'flag':[0,1]})
```

Comment: Please post expected output and reason

Comment: @Aditya.Kommu added

Comment: What is your new column condition? and also Column A? it is not clear

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to extract or explain a bit further? it's hard to understand where this output is coming from

Answer (score 0):

To find **indices** of both rows of interest, run:

```
ind1 = df[df.flag.shift(-1).eq(0) & df.flag.shift(-2).eq(1)].index[0]
ind2 = df[df.index > ind1].B.idxmin()
```

For your data sample the result is *2* and *6*.

Then, to retrieve **rows** with these indices, run:

```
df.loc[[ind1, ind2]]
```

The result is:

```
   A  B  flag
2  4  4     0
6  1  1     1
```